# Static IP Address Not Assignable to Load Balancer in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am trying to assign a static IP address to my Traefik ingress load balancer, but always get the same response on Google Cloud:

```
Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load   balancer for service default/traefik-service: requested ip   "35.185.139.44" is neither static nor assigned to the LB
coffee:gke Steven$ glcoud compute addresses list
```

I do notice all static  are in the RESERVED and non say IN USE

```
# Declare Traefik ingress service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-service
spec:
  selector:
   app: traefik-gke-demo
   tier: reverse-proxy
  ports:
   - port: 80
     name: http
   - port: 443
     name: https
   - port: 8080
     name: admin
   type: LoadBalancer
   loadBalancerIP:  35.185.xx.xx
```

Comment: Did you create a static ip? `gcloud compute addresses list`

Comment: I have currently similar case, I didn't reserve IP myself and I don't know how to check it reservation settings. I suspect it was set only of internal use (even it is in public ip range) like for Ingress

Answer (score 0):

Service declaration is correct, 
Google Container Engine running Kubernetes v1.1 supports `loadBalancerIP`, you just need to created static IP for your project beforehand, i.e.

```
gcloud compute addresses create traefik-static-lb

gcloud compute addresses list
```

Once reserved, create LB service

**UPD:**

Here is an example of my LB service with assigned static IP:

```
sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ gcloud compute addresses list
NAME            ADDRESS/RANGE   TYPE      PURPOSE  NETWORK  REGION        SUBNET  STATUS
test-static-ip  35.198.94.139   EXTERNAL                    europe-west3          IN_USE


sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ kk get svc rabbitmq-management
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)           AGE
rabbitmq-management   LoadBalancer   10.59.241.225   35.198.94.139   15672:31728/TCP   4d


sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ kk get svc rabbitmq-management -oyaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq-management
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.59.241.225
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  loadBalancerIP: 35.198.94.139
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31728
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: yes, I have static ip addresses. the problem is that it does not seem possible to assign this IP address to a load balancer service.  It can be assigned to an ingress yes.

Comment: @StevenSmart technically it is possible, I have updated my answer with  example of LB svc with static IP.  If you have issues with this, check stackdriver logs, it might be some local issues.

Answer (score -1):

Kubernetes Engine will auto-magically provision a TCP (!) load-balancer for you  using the Google Cloud Load-Balancer (GCLB) when you apply a `Service` spec with `type: LoadBalancer`

So, remove `loadBalancerIP: 35.185.139.44` and `kubectl apply --filename=...` without it, wait briefly and then `kubectl get service/traefik-service` and you should see that the LB provisions the service for you.

Alternatively:

```sh
kubectl get services \
--selector=app=traefik-gke-demo,tier=reverse-proxy \
--output=jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
```

and some variant of the following to confirm the load-balancer is provisioned:

```sh
gcloud compute forwarding-rules list \
--format="value(IPAddress) \
--project=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
```

**NB** Using `Service` this way will provision a TCP load-balancer. If you would prefer an HTTP|L7 load-balancer, then you should use an `Ingress`.

Comment: I am trying to use a static IP address.  Is there a way to tell google to auto-magically use a static IP address for the load balancer?

Comment: I am trying to use my own load balancer as opposed to google cloud load balancer or if using the gcloud than at least be able to set the IP address of the load balancer.

Comment: My bad. Sorry, your question was clear. The issue is that you can't then tell the `Service` to be `type: LoadBalancer` because that's defined in Kubernetes Engine to provision the L4 LB. I think perhaps the way to do this is via an `Ingress` and defining the `Service` using `NodePort`. Let me do some research.

Comment: Hmmm... Wrong again: https://github.com/Zenika/traefik-gke-demo/blob/master/scripts/gke/08_traefik_service.yml I don't know. Let's see what others have to say.

Comment: ok well I was able to assign it an ingress but not a loadbalancer. That works